# How can I add an object inside another object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

My question is simple, I have 2 objects like this:

```
object1 = {
    content1: {}
}

object2 = {
    stuff: {},
    moreStuff: {}
}
```

And I want to add the content of **object2** to **content1** (which is inside of **object1**).

Like this:

```
object1 = {
    content1: {
        stuff: {},
        moreStuff: {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is very simple;

`object1.content1 = object2`

Answer (score 10):

This will allow you to add an object inside another object.
 
With other examples you will get a substitution instead of **adding**.
e.g.

```js
const obj1 = {
 innerObj:{
   name:'Bob'
  },
  innerOBj2:{
   color:'blue'
  }
}

const obj2 = {
 lastName:'Some',
  age:45
}

obj1.innerObj = Object.assign(obj1.innerObj,obj2);
console.log(obj1);
```

Now if you need something more advance, you should take a look to some functional programming framework like **ramda**, which will allow you to merge object. **R.merge**.

Answer (score 3):

Something keeping you from doing: `object1.content1 = object2` ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
object1.content1 = object2;
```

Answer (score 3):

Initialization

```
var object1 = {
   content1:"1"
}
var object2 = {
   content2:"2",
   content3:"3"
}
```

Put contents of object2 into object1's content1

```
object1.content1 = object2;//this is the code you are looking for


console.log(object2);
```

You are done!